# Drag and Drop control add-in not working on Dynamics 365 BC

Tags: dynamics-business-central

[local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMhnQ.png)

I have a issue where a company running on the server doesn't show the Drag and drop option in a form, When I run the same company on a local win 10 machine with localhost it runs and i have the drag and drop feature available. Kindly help, how can I[server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1avrs.png) fix this?

Comment: What version of Business Central are you using? Is it OnPrem og Cloud?

Comment: @kaspermoerch Am using On prem. BC v17.0.16974.0

Answer (score 0):

After several tries of getting down to what could be the issue turns out the problem was the drag and drop add-in I was using at the beginning was only supporting http that's why when I tested it on local machine it show the drag and drop feature but with HTTPS it wasn't working.
Had to create a new add-in to support HTTPs and that solved the issue.